# Your report has an error and couldn 't be processed!\ Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console

Tags: php, jasper-reports

**I try to generate pdf from PHPJasper and this error come and i cannot find a solution for. Please tel me answer or any other way to generate reports**

> "Your report has an error and couldn 't be processed!\ Try to output
>   the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the
>   console."

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPJasper\PHPJasper;  

try{               
    $input = __DIR__ . '/Report/Coffee.jasper';  
    $output = __DIR__ . '/Report';    
    $options = ['format' => ['pdf']];

    $jasper = new PHPJasper;

    $jasper->process($input, $output, $options)->execute();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the output() command as mentioned in the message?

You can try something easy as this and check the output of it:

```
$x = $jasper->process(
            $input,
            $output,
            $options
            )->output();
            print_r($x);
exit(1);//just to avoid getting error handler on your framework
```

Sometimes that will tell you more information. If it shows the command line to execute, try executing it directly on your command line, you might get more information there.

Common things to consider:
- The user (probably the Web server user in your case) has no access or write access to the folder where you are creating the file
- Perhaps the line was already generated before, and the error is that the file already exists. Try generating a random name for each report generation to avoid this; or generate the file, serve it in the application and delete it

Comment: I tried as you show in your answer and then i get a error showing  **jasperstarter process "C:\wamp64\www\myphp\web_app/Report/Coffee.jrxml" -o "C:\wamp64\www\myphp\web_app/Report" -f pdf**

Comment: That is the command line which is going to be executed by "PHPJasper".

So go to windows command line, ("cmd"), inside the folder where the executable "jasperstarter.exe" is located, and executed manually (copy/paste it). 

Whatever message you get there, is the first thing to solve

Comment: Thank you for answer i did that and i shows a error msg and regarding the image and i fix it.then i try to execute the report but only appears a blank page.report still not showing. i cmd also not showing any errors now.

Comment: Hello i found that its shows black page but pdf file is creating in the output directory.thank you for you answer.any way if you please let me proper way to view the pdf file in the browser after executing it. thank you.because since im creating a POS system i want bill to be view to print.

Comment: @gumaterror I tried your suggestion, pasting the the output as a command in Windows Powershell in the directory where jasperstarter.exe resides, but I get a `jasperstarter : The term 'jasperstarter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` error. What am I missing? I checked the spelling of "jasperstarter" and it's fine. I think this should work.

Comment: @Hondaman900 i think that is more a question of a powershell, than PHPJasper, you can check that error on other threads about powershell and folder permissions